# Open source Version of NetworkView software

Tags: networking

NetworkView is a software that allows us to identify devices in a network range . 
Here is the website . http://www.networkview.com/

I  would have liked  to make some tweaks to how it works etc  to customize it for my application .

However unfortunately , it is not open sourced . 
Does anyone know of a similar tool but is open source . 
would be of great help

Thanks

Comment: The closest thing I know of is Wireshark, but that seems like only a partial solution. You'd need something to interpret the data from it to get the rest of the way to Network View, it would seem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) used to great effect, and it is open source. I also have used Mikrotik's [The Dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude.php) for network management but sadly it is not open source, but certainly very versatile!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at NeDi? http://www.nedi.ch/_media/nedi-flyer11.pdf